# Returning long pointer value from unmanaged DLL entry point

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, dll, unmanaged

I have one entry point in my unmanaged DLL and this is the code from its C code

```
void *__cdecl entryp(int a1, int a2, __int64 a3, signed int a4, int a5)
{
  void *v6; 
  /..../
  /..../

  return v6;
}
```

and i use dllimport on my C# project with this

```
[DllImport("unmanaged.dll", EntryPoint = "entryp",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern unsafe long* entryp(byte[] bData, uint length, ushort width, ushort heigth, uint nMaxCode, short anaLevel);
```

but the problem is the method just does not return anything
whats going wrong with my code? Thanks for reading my question

Comment: The question is "what does v6 point to?"  It is undefined behavior to return the address of a local variable.

Comment: Those methods have completely different arguments.  Is this a typo in the question?

Comment: what is the difference? @dbc

Comment: @masbro - one is `int a1, int a2, __int64 a3, signed int a4, int a5`, other is `byte[] bData, uint length, ushort width, ushort heigth, uint nMaxCode, short anaLevel`

Comment: no its because the two method written with different language so its need to do conversion to its parameter

Answer (score 0):

The code in the DLL must be exported, so I'd expect the declaration to be:

```
void* __declspec(dllexport) entryp(int a1, int a2, __int64 a3, signed int a4, int a5)
{
  //...
}
```